# Determine if the hyperbolic and exponential functions are linearly dependent or independent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

The given set of functions is 
$$[ \sinh(x),\space\cosh(x),  e^x]$$
$\begin{bmatrix} \sinh(x) \space \cosh(x) \space e^{-x}\\ \cosh(x) \space \space \sinh(x) \space -e^{-x}\\ \sinh(x) \space \cosh(x) \space e^{-x} \end{bmatrix}$

Using the matrix above I multiplied through, taking the Wronskian of the given functions and it's given derivatives. After further factoring and addition  I calculated the equation to be
$$e^{-x}(\cosh(2x) +\sinh(2x))=0 $$
Then using hyperbolic identities to rewrite the trig. terms I got
$$ e^{-x} \left(\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2} \right)=0$$ 
$$e^{-x}(e^{2x})=0$$
$$e^{-x} \ne0$$
There for the set of functions is linearly independent.
Are my calculations and verdict correct?

[image]

Comment: What exactly is it that you’re trying to verify is linearly independent? The determinant in (c) is obviously equal to zero since the first and last rows are identical.

Comment: @amd So its Dependent.

Comment: What’s the “it,” though? You still haven’t mentioned _anywhere_ what it is you’re trying to show independence of for any of the three exercises in your scribblings here.

Comment: You should also use MathJax instead of submitting screen shots of your homework.

Comment: @amd "Scribblings"?